# Translating DNA data to amino acid in phylip format

Tags: python, translate

I have DNA data in Phylip format that I would like to translate to amino acid. I've tried searching for libraries (or modules) that can do this but all of which seem to translate/produce files in FastA format.

This is how the input data looks:

```
3 1500

seq1  TTTGCTA...

seq2  TTCGCAA...

seq3  TTTGCCA...
```

where 1500 is the length of the sequences

This is the code I have but the output file I'm getting is empty:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

filename = '/path/to/phylip/data/'
finalrst = open('/path/to/translated/phylip/data/','w')


def translate_dna(sequence):

    codontable = {
    'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
    'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
    'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
    'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
    'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
    'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
    'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
    'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
    'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
    'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
    'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'*', 'TAG':'*',
    'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'*', 'TGG':'W',
    'ATG':'M'
    }
    proteinsequence = ''
    for n in range (0,len(sequence),3):
            if sequence[n:n+3] in codontable:
                    proteinsequence += codontable[cds[n:n+3]]
            sequence = ''
    print proteinsequence

for line in open(filename):
    if line[0] == "3 1500":
        finalrst.write(line)
    elif line == '':
        finalrst.write(line)
    elif line.startswith('sequence'):
            finalrst.write(line + translate_dna(line.replace('sequence', '')))

finalrst.close()
```

Any suggestions on what the issue is? or perhaps a better way of getting at this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are those filepaths to folders or a file?  If `data` is a file, take the `/` off the end. If it's a folder path then you need to specify the file you want to open.

Then, just for the sake of sanity change this:

```
for line in open(filename):
    if line[0] == "3 1500":
        finalrst.write(line)
    elif line == '':
        finalrst.write(line)
    elif line.startswith('sequence'):
        finalrst.write(line + translate_dna(line.replace('sequence', '')))
```

To something like this:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as readfile:
    for line in readfile:
        line = line.strip()
        # Check the full line, stripped instead of the first character.
        if line == "3 1500":
            finalrst.write(line + '\n')
        elif line == '':
            finalrst.write(line + '\n')
        elif line.startswith('sequence'):
            finalrst.write(line + translate_dna(line.replace('sequence', '')) + '\n')
```

This way the `readfile` file handle will always get closed.

But it's probably because of the filepaths pointing to a folder.  If it's not that it may be because of the lingering file handle that was opened, but not closed.

Comment: Thanks this helped! One more question: I am resorting to using elif line.startswith('seq1'):
    finalrst.write('seq1\t' + translate_dna(line.split()[-1]) + '\n') .. for all sequences in the dataset, any suggestions on how to get the code to recognize the sequence name and (1) not translate it and (2) write  it before the translated data?

Comment: @Hia3, I would type this up as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Your translate_dna doesn't appear to work. Here is a working approach albeit not the most optimal

```
def translate_dna(sequence):
    sequence = sequence.upper()

    codontable = {
    'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
    'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K',
    'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
    'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L',
    'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
    'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q',
    'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
    'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V',
    'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
    'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E',
    'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
    'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S',
    'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
    'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'*', 'TAG':'*',
    'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'*', 'TGG':'W',
    'ATG':'M'
    }

    translated = ''
    while len(sequence) >=3:
        substring_3 = sequence[:3]
        if substring_3 in codontable:
            translated+= codontable[substring_3]
            sequence = sequence[1:]
        else:
            sequence = sequence[3:]

    return translated
```

Also, there are other problems. For example:

```
elif line.startswith('sequence'):
    finalrst.write(line + translate_dna(line.replace('sequence', '')))
```

There is no string 'sequence' in your input. Make it:

```
elif line.startswith('seq'):
    finalrst.write(line + '\t' + translate_dna(line.split()[-1]))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked (with some additions from the other reply) except I had to change sequence = sequence[1:] to sequence = sequence[3:] since the way it was read for example ATTGTC as ATT, TTG, TGT, and so on rather than ATT, GTC.